# solving homogenous system with complex eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the system

$\frac{dx}{dt}=2x+8y$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-x-2y$

When I solve the determinant of the matrix, I get $\lambda=\pm 2i$. Then , I plug it in the matrix, and get  the for the first eigenvalue, $\lambda=2i$:

$0=(2-2i)x+8y$

$0=-x-(2+2i)y$

This gives

$x=\frac{-8}{2-2i}y$

$x=-(2+2i)y$

All the examples in the book are "nice" examples where one can immediately deduce the eigenvectors by sheer rapid look, but here, I am not sure. Is there a trick to identify the eigenvector from two equations that are not similar, such as these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{-8}{2-2i} = \frac{-8(2+2i)}{(2-2i)(2+2i)} = \frac{-8(2+2i)}{8} = -(2+2i)
,
$$
so the two equations are saying the same thing (as they *must*, if the eigenvalues are correctly computed). So you can simply take, for example, $y=-1$ and $x=2+2i$ to get an eigenvector.

Comment: I get it. One HAS to simplify a fractional complex number if one gets it, in order to spot that everything is right, and one ALWAYS gets one eigenvector pr eigenvalue. If one gets two, something is wrong. Thanks!