# Assessing stability or instability of a system of equations with complex eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Having [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354076/solving-homogenous-system-with-complex-eigenvalues#4354083) system
, we get clearly two complex eigenvalues. If one has to assess the stability of the system at these eigenvalues, we have for the matrix A:

\begin{pmatrix}
 a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}

that $T^2-4\Delta \geq  or \leq or = 0$, where  $T=a+c$, while  $\Delta=ad-bc=DetA$. But with complex eigenvalues  $\pm2i$, $T$ which must be real, becomes complex and $\Delta$ is always $0$, when it would vary from greater than or lesser than zero for real eigenvalues. How do we solve this with complex eigenvalues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the eigenvalues are pure imaginary, then the system has only a center.
If the eigenvalues are complex, the *non-zero real part*  (call it $\alpha)$ of the term $T^2-4\Delta$ defines whether it is a stable or unstable spiral - for $\alpha > 0$, then it is a unstable spiral point, and inversely, $\alpha<0$ then it is a stable spiral.